# Laravel how to pass filter response to controller action

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I am using filter on route and after filtering results I want to send filter response to controller action. Here is my code.

```
 Route::post('user/{id}/login', array(
      'as'    => 'routename',
      'uses'  => 'Controller@action',
      'before' => ['Exists_User', 'Exist_Registration']
    ));
```

Now in filters .php

```
Route::filter('Exist_Registration', 'Path-to-registration-filter-class');
```

I can var dump response and I can see filter is working.

And here is the filter.

```
class Registration {

    protected $reg;
    protected $user;

    public function __construct(RegRepository $registration, URepository $User){
        $this->reg = $registration;
        $this->user = $User;
    }

    public function filter(Route $route) {

        if (!$this->reg->findByUserID($route->getParameter('id')))
        {
            \Auth::loginUsingId($route->getParameter('id'));

            return Response::json(array(
                'success' => true,
                'url' =>  URL::route('enrollment.show')
            ));
        }
    }
}
```

Now how can get this response in controller action.

Comment: You should be able to use controller if there is no error message.

Comment: Actually I think my understanding of filters is wrong in this situation. Filters are middleware to prevent calls that shouldn't reach to controller so rest of the logic should be in controller.

Comment: Yes filters allow or deny requests. And  yes the logic should be in controller.